# Automatically update cache version after each commit

Tags: caching, automation, command

I want some off my requests not to be cached everytime I make a change on the site.  That's why I use a variable App.cacheVersion that I increment everytime I have changed something.

My code looks something like this:

```
<html>
<script>
App.cacheVersion=12
</script>
$http.get(url+"?cache="+App.cacheVersion)
</html>
```

This way, I'm sure the content of the URL will not be cached everytime I update my app. However, I have to manually change App.cacheVersion everytime before I commit. Is they a way to automate that (I know of git hooks, but I would like to see the script I should use) ?

If yes, I'd like that the command work on Windows and OS X.